# Optimize Android Studio - Minimize the impact of antivirus software on build speed

Tags: android, windows, performance, jetbrains-ide, virus

In latest android studio version's will popup a msg that telling below state

> Your anti-virus program might be impacting your build performance. Android Studio checked the following ...

And the details info is explained here publically. ->
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?utm_source=android-studio#antivirus-impact

I'm not sure about the safety of the application and my PC, I can force-add the application to the exclusions list.The problem is that by forcing the antivirus to ignore the potential danger and subjecting the computer data to the risk of infection. Even a perfectly legitimate app can be compromised. Isn't there any other solution other than the excluding or any?

Comment: As per link provided by you they are not asking to add the application to exclusion list, They are just **advising to disable Real Time Scanning on certain folders** basically you can disable Real Time Scanning on build folder of your project.

Comment: Yeah, and after a person who knows about the exclusion list can inject any script. Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution.
If you care more about pseudo security than about build performance just click "Actions" -> "Don't show again".

Comment: Ha haa... You make my day